# TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-ui

I am using jquery and jquery ui for drag and drop functionality inside angular project for which i have added,

Index.html:

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Component.ts:

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

export class DropAreaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      ngOnInit(): void {
        $("#people").sortable({
          update: function(e, ui) {
            $("#people .draggable").each(function(i, element) {
              $(element).attr("id", $(element).index("#people .draggable"));
              $(element).text($(element).text().split("Index")[0] + " " + "Index: " + " => " + $(element).attr("id"));
            });
          }
        });
}
```

Component.html:

```
<ul id="people">
    <li *ngFor="let person of people; let i = index">
      <div class="draggable" id={{i}}>
        <p> <b> {{ person.name }} </b> Index => {{i}}</p>
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But it is showing the error as,

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
```

angular-cli.json consists of the following in scripts,

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.min.js",
    "../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
    "../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
    "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"
],
```

Is there any issues with the script in angular-cli.json when i am including in `index.html`?
Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missing : jquery-ui.min.js

- run npm install jquery-ui-dist
- add path in script (add after jquery include line)

  ../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js

Remove following script from index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```